# How can I determine if my process is being run interactively?

Tags: ruby, command-line, process, environment

Is there a standard(ish) POSIX way of determining if my process (I’m writing this as a Ruby script right now; but I’m curious for multiple environments, including Node.js and ISO C command-line applications) is being run in an interactive terminal, as opposed to, say, cron, or execution from another tool, or… so on and so forth.

Specifically, I need to acquire user input in certain situations, and I need to fail fatally if that is determinably *not possible* (i.e. being run by cron.) I can do this with an environment variable, but I’d prefer something more standard-ish, if I can.

Comment: For anyone who came here looking for windows, try System.Environment.UserInteractive for .Net or GetUserObjectInformation for win32, which will fail for non-interactive processes.

Comment: You could have added that as an actual answer, and gotten reputation from it. (=

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've always used `$stdout.isatty` to check for this. Other approaches might include checking the value of `ENV['TERM']` or utilizing the [ruby-terminfo](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-terminfo) gem.

Comment: `isatty` seems to be part of ruby IO class: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-isatty

Comment: `ENV['TERM']` is not a good idea, as if you run a Ruyb command from terminal and redirect its output (`ruby script.rb >someFile.txt`), then `$TERM` will of course be set, but `$stdout` will not be a TTY.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you'll get, AFAIK, is [isatty()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html). But as the page itself says, nothing guarantees that a human is controlling the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mitch wrote it in a comment, which can also be useful to some people:

> For anyone who came here looking for windows, try `System.Environment.UserInteractive` for .Net or `GetUserObjectInformation` for win32, which will fail for non-interactive processes